# How to Enable Support for Mixed Languages Arabic and English Where one is RTL and Another is LTR

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

```
var inputValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) } // 2
val isRtl = if (inputValue.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    val firstChar = inputValue.text[0]
    Bidi.getBaseDirection(firstChar.toString()) == Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT.toByte()
} else {
    false
}

fun sendMessage() { // 3
    callback(inputValue.text)
    inputValue = TextFieldValue("")
}

Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = inputValue,
        onValueChange = { inputValue = it },
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Message") },
        shape = RectangleShape,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)
            .heightIn(max = 200.dp),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.None
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSend = { sendMessage() }),
        leadingIcon = {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_edit_note_24),
                contentDescription = "Person",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
            )
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { sendMessage() },
                enabled = inputValue.text.isNotBlank(),
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Send,
                    contentDescription = "Send",
                    tint = if (inputValue.text.isNotBlank()) green else Color.White,
                )
            }
        },
        textStyle = if (isRtl) LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl) else LocalTextStyle.current,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            cursorColor = green,
        )
    )
```

Here i am using this to change the directions of the textfield when the user uses RTL languages
and it handles this fine but if you add emoji or any LTR language like English it causes the
text stored to be inverted.
Example
this is the input
قق rrrrv. تتتت ع
and it is stored like below
تتتت ع  rrrrv. قق
I want to fix this issue how can i do it

I wanted that when the user starts entering input in RTL make the text field direction RTL to
get the input and if the user mixes the language make it maintain RTL and then stores the value

But when storing their values are shifted in the variable while using a text to shoe them.

How can i Fix this